# Power Automate Trigger Conditions for specific column in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow

I have a SharePoint list that I want to trigger the flow by using **Trigger Conditions** when the specific column value changes.
[image]
[image]

The flow triggered when the Current Status changed to Approved but the flow triggered again when I changed the value on the Amount column. which I don’t want to happen. I want the flow to trigger when the Current Status column value changes and ignore other columns' modifications. I tried the below trigger conditions but not working properly.

[image]

@equals(triggerBody()?['Current_Status']?['Value'],'APPROVED')

AND

@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Current_Status/Value'],'APPROVED')

Comment: Keep hidden column in the list like "IsFlowRunning" and set it's value to "Yes" at the start of flow using "Update item" action. Then add trigger condition based on this column AND status column. Let me know if this approach works for you.